# jQuery if element is visible, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, navigation

I am trying to detect if an element is visible and then assigning a function to it:

After the menu button is shown with the button, I want to click anywhere and hide the meny and re-show the button.

```
if ($('ul.site-nav.actual-navigation').css('display') == 'block') {
    $(document).click(function() {
        $('ul.site-nav.actual-navigation').hide();
        $('button.nav-mobile-switch').show();
    });

}
```

I did try the `$('element:visible')` and `$('element').is(':visible')` methods as well.

I read somewhere that the psuedo selector `:visible` doesn't work with functions, but the example here doesn't hide the element when I click anywhere either.

What have I done wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/yuAhb/

Comment: What's wrong? In your fiddle, the button disappears and the menu shows (I'm using Chrome). What is supposed to happen instead?

Comment: Could you try explaining _what_ you're trying to do here?

Comment: Then you need to embed one click handler inside the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that `if` at all; and you are not using it right as described in the answer of @SLaks.
Why won't you assign functions to an invisible element? I guess we should do that, so I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/yuAhb/1/

```
 $('button.nav-mobile-switch').click(function () {
     $(this).hide();
     $('ul.site-nav.actual-navigation').show();
     return false;
 });

 $(document).click(function () {
     $('ul.site-nav.actual-navigation').hide();
     $('button.nav-mobile-switch').show();
 });


 $('ul.site-nav.actual-navigation').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried before the `if` stuff I started with. Now it works, wth? :D Thanks.

Comment: Self-healing code probably, also I've added a `return false;` to the first handler ;)

Answer (score 5):

You're only checking the visibility when the page first loads.
Nothing runs that code again when the menu is actually visible.

Instead, you add the handler immediately, but make it not do anything if the element isn't visible.
Alternatively, you could only add the handler when you show the element, and remove it when you hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
$('ul.site-nav.actual-navigation').live('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).css('display') == 'block') {
    //code
  }
});
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. Use `.on` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the visible selector but functions don't work with the visibility attribute.:-

```
$('element:visible')
```

So you can try this. Remove the if condition and use this:-

```
$(document).click(function () {
     $('ul.site-nav.actual-navigation').hide();
     $('button.nav-mobile-switch').show();
 });
```

It will hide the menu and show the button.

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kH7Fd/)